# Netbeans: How do I disable this?

Tags: netbeans

[image: Netbeans annoying popup]

How do I disable this annoying black box that pops up in Netbeans? I want to keep code hints etc enabled, but this continually annoys me and I can't find the setting for it.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming Netbeans 7.0 +

Select Tools from the Top menu bar

-> Options

-> click on Editor ( looks like a book )

-> select the tab labeled "hints"

-> from the pull down menu choose the correct language

-> deselect the hint for that feature

If Thats a documentation prompt then

-> select the tab labeled "Code Completion"

->deselect "Auto Popup Documentation Window"

In my Neatbeans however HINTS or DOCs are never on black background so i can't rule out that you have a addon or plugin that may be causing this ...

Comment: If you deselect ALL the hints and restart netbeans does the problem go away ?

Comment: Also worth noting that on both a mac and PC i tested here i could not get that box to pop up when entering the visible lines. Any chance you have a another program or help that could be putting that up ?